# Sort table by character

Tags: sql

I am at a slight loss when it comes to ordering a table in a specific way. Basically I have a table of items as a max 2 character string;

```
A
B
..
Y
Z
AA
AB
AC
AD
```

I would like for the sort function to arrange the characters as portrayed above where AA will follow after Z. If I sort using a standard **ORDER BY [Character] ASC** then the queried table will obviously look like so;

```
A
AA
AB
AC
AD
B
C
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
order by len(Character), Character
```

Note that some databases use `length()` instead of `len()`.